# What if Java prints the NUL character?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] array = new char[2];
    array[0] = 'a';
    String s = new String(array);
    assert s.length() == 2;
    System.out.print(">" + s + "<\n");
    System.out.print(">" + s.substring(1) + "<\n");
    System.out.print("end of test.\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
>a
>
end of test
```

Unlike C, the Java string is not null character terminated, hence the assertion is true. Why doesn't Java print the `<` delimiting symbol?

EDIT: Possibly relevant is that this is in Eclipse 4.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It prints it out for me. Could it be your terminal which is causing it?

Comment: Right. Inside Eclipse the behavior is wrong. On the command line it worked.

Comment: Works for me in Eclipse 4.5.2.

Comment: Strange title btw.

Comment: "What happened to the less than sign" is more descriptive but probably not informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code in Eclipse and everything *seems* to works fine.

However, if I copy/paste the output from Eclipse console and paste it on a text editor it pastes only what you mentioned `>a`.

I am even pasting this `>a` copied/pasted from the Eclipse console (when I see  `>a <`... look at my screenshot below).

So, I added this little code snippet to your code:

```
String f = " >" + s + "<\n";
for (int i=0; i < f.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println((int)f.charAt(i));
}
```

And this was the ascii codes:

```
32
62
97
0
60
10
```

I think your console has conflict printing the `NUL` (or `0`) character. Additionally, I tested this on Windows so it wouldn't surprise me that Windows has problem copying/pasting strings with `NUL` in the middle.

This is a screenshot from my eclipse and output:
[image]

Comment: It's interesting that the non-printable null occupies whitespace on your console. I would not have expected that. On my console, there's no whitespace.

Comment: @H2ONaCl it called my attention too, but what called my attention the most... is copying and pasting the content into a text editor. Seems the clipboard is borked with `NUL` character

Comment: I have seen strange things happen sometimes when passing `NUL` characters to things, even when those strings aren't usually null-terminated, since everything after the `NUL` is lost if the string is ever converted to a C string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    >a <
    > <
    end of test
```

I can't replicate your ouput - this is the output I'm getting in BlueJay, Eclipse, and NetBeans. Have you attempted this in different IDEs to confirm that this is happening every time?

Comment: If it works on the command line then I'm not going to worry about the IDE much.

Comment: @H2ONaCl alright man. Cheers - good to hear that it's working there

Comment: My command line prints `>a<`. Not exactly the same as yours.